# Java 8 Method Signature different versions of same method

Tags: java, java-8

**Version 1**

```
interface HelloWorld{
    String hello(String s);
}
HelloWorld h = String::new;
h.hello("Something");
```

**Version 2**

```
interface HelloWorld{
    void hello(String s);
}
HelloWorld h = String::new;
h.hello("Something");
```

**Version 3**

```
interface HelloWorld{
    String hello();
}
HelloWorld h = String::new;
h.hello();
```

**Version 4**

```
 interface HelloWorld{
     void hello();
 }
 HelloWorld h = String::new;
 h.hello();
```

I have created four versions of the same code but I didn't change `HelloWorld h = String::new;`
First case I am able to understand, it creates new Object of String with value passed in the argument and returns the object.

Can some elaborate it why compiler is not giving any error in other cases with some explanation?

Comment: Where is `hello` method defined?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 6):

In Version 1 sand Version 2, your `String::new` method reference is referring to the `public String(String original)` constructor of the `String` class.

In Version 3 sand Version 4, your `String::new` method reference is referring to the `public String()` constructor of the `String` class.

It doesn't matter whether the method of your functional interface returns a `String` or has a `void` return type. Either way, the relevant `String::new` method reference fits the signature of your interface's method.

Perhaps writing the Java 7 equivalents would make this easier to understand:

Version 1:

```
HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld () {
    String getSomething(String s) {
        return new String(s);
    }
}
```

Version 2:

```
HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld () {
    void getSomething(String s) {
        new String(s);
    }
}
```

Version 3:

```
HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld () {
    String getSomething() {
        return new String();
    }
}
```

Version 4:

```
HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld () {
    void getSomething() {
        new String();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is provided in the specification? I was trying to find from long time and your solution helped me..

Comment: @PrasadReddy Are you asking where in the JLS this is explained?

Comment: @PrasadReddy There is no `Consumer` or `Supplier` involved in your code. You are using a custom functional interface (`HelloWorld`).

Comment: Where can i get the documentation ?

Comment: @PrasadReddy You can read about method references [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13)